# R using RMariaDB unable to connect with .mylogin.cnf

Tags: mysql, r, configuration-files, my.cnf, rmariadb

I'm developing a script in RStudio which connects to local MySQL Server using the R package RMariaDB (not RMySQL - for other reasons though the outcome is the same).

I can both connect via storing the password in the script like:

```
localuserpassword <- "password"

all_projectsDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='user', password=localuserpassword, dbname='projects', host='localhost')
```

or by way of a .my.cnf using credentials:

```
[client]
[mygroup]
host=127.0.0.1
user=user
password=password
port=3306
database=projects
```

and R code as

```
settingsfile = '/Users/oscar_w/.my.cnf'

all_projectsDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), default.file = settingsfile, group="mygroup", dbname = 'projects')
```

The above work just fine but if I want to connect with .mylogin.cnf created in mysql_config_editor and looks like

```
[client]
[mygroup]
user = user
password = *****
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 3306
```

with the R script code like

```
# define location of config file
settingsfile = '/Users/oscar_w/.mylogin.cnf'

all_projectsDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), default.file = settingsfile, group="mygroup", dbname = 'projects', password = NULL, user = NULL)
```

I get the error

```
Error: Failed to connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have tried various combinations of arguments expressing null or otherwise. And have entered my password with mysql_config_editor with double quotes around it. In https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMariaDB/RMariaDB.pdf it specifies the use of .mylogin.cnf but I cannot find a way to make it work. Does anyone know a solution to this or has the same issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to log in both with and without a password, which isn't allowed. The RMariaDB documentation says that if the password argument is NULL or omitted, only users without a password can log in.